# How would I rearrange this equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need to make "r" the subject of this equation, but whatever I try I get a ridiculously small number. If anybody could walk me through exactly how to rearrange it, describing why they do each step I would be hugely grateful

$\frac{(sin(\theta))}{(cos(\theta))} = \frac{(220^2)}{g*r}$

Comment: What are $g$ and $\theta$?

Answer (score 1):

we have $$\tan(\theta)=\frac{220^2}{gr}$$ and by cross muultiplication we obtain
$$\frac{1}{\tan(\theta)}=\frac{gr}{220^2}$$ and finally we get
$$\frac{220^2}{\tan(\theta)\cdot g}=r$$

Answer (score 0):

You might like to simplify things a little by rewriting the right-hand side as $\tan\theta$. Multiplying both sides by $r/\tan\theta$ then gives $r=48400/(g\tan\theta)$.

Answer (score 0):

You can write 
$$r = \frac{(220^2\cos(\theta))}{g \sin(\theta)}$$
if $\theta \neq 0 \quad [\pi]$.